# Is there a way in Java to call a method on an already-running object in a separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

The idea is, an object already is executing some method and perhaps you want to invoke a different method that will only begin to execute when the first method is finished. The only way that occurs to me is to pass a message via a member that is visible to the thread and the object will check the message, executing the appropriate method and perhaps depositing the results of that method in a place where the first thread can see this. Perhaps there is a more elegant approach?

EDIT: I am reading about the asynchronous annotation or Spring's asynch annotation and it appears that this might be what I need...

Comment: There isn't really any such thing as an "already-running object."  The only things that ever "run" in a Java program are the threads.  The methods are _what_ the threads run, and the objects are the _data_ that the methods instruct the threads to operate on.

Comment: When you want one thread to wait for another (e.g., "...to invoke a different method that will only begin to execute when..."), that's where the classes in `java.util.concurrent` come in handy.  A `SynchronousQueue` for example is a handy way for one thread to hand off a "message" or a "token" to another thread.  `Semaphore`, and `CountDownLatch` and other `java.util.concurrent` classes can also be used if the token does not need to be an explicit object.

Comment: If a method was invoked and is the code being run, can a second method be invoked and if so, what happens to the first method -- is it interrupted?

Comment: OK, picture a classroom.  The teacher writes a list of instructons on the whiteboard, and each student follows the instructions at his/her own pace.  A method is like the list of instructions, and the threads are like the students.  The threads do whatever the methods say to do, but the methods don't know or care about the threads---just like the whiteboard doesn't know or care how many students are following the instructions.  Any number of threads can execute the same method at the same time if there's no synchronization that prevents it.

Comment: You need synchronization when different threads access the same _data_.  If the instructions on the whiteboard say, "...write the answer on your test form."  no problem, because each student has his/her own form.  But, if the instructions say, "...write your answer in the blank here: ____________", then that's a problem because there's 23 students and only one blank.  Use `synchronized` in Java to prevent multiple threads from accessing the same shared data at the same time.  Use BlockingQueues, Semaphores, etc.  to coordinate threads in other, more sophisticated ways.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: I am thinking of code running in a single thread, not multiple threads. Or maybe to be precise two threads, a main and a thread that is created to run code. If code from an object is running in the thread, can indeed a second method be invoked causing this code to run and if so, does this happen immediately or will the code that is already running complete before the second method is invoked?

Comment: Every program has at least one thread:  Your `main(...)` routine is called by a thread that is implicitly created when the JVM starts up.  If your program creates one thread, then it will have _two_ threads.  Two threads _is_ "multiple threads."  Nothing prevents two (or more) threads from running the same method at the same time or, methods on the same object at the same time or, methods of the same class at the same time...  Nothing, that is, unless you use `synchronized` to prevent it.  Please work your way through the tutorial (see the link I posted above.)

Answer (score 0):

Add `synchronized` to both methods.

Try running the following with and without the synchronized keyword.

```
public class SynchronizedMethods {

    public synchronized void longRunningMethodA() {
        System.out.println("Method A - Start");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        System.out.println("Method A - End"); 
    }

    public synchronized void longRunningMethodB() {
        System.out.println("Method B - Start");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        System.out.println("Method B - End"); 
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SynchronizedMethods object = new SynchronizedMethods();

        new Thread() {public void run() {
            object.longRunningMethodB();
        }}.start();

        object.longRunningMethodA();
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: How would you compare your approach to: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: This approach is pure Java, requires only 2 added keywords (no libraries or learning curve), and has worked for 20 years :D   You can also return Futures instead of void if that's something you need.  Cheers.